# PDO throwing error

Tags: php, pdo

I'm going crazy looking for the error in the following PDO SELECT statement:

```
$get_allocation_id = "
  SELECT id
  FROM form1_group_info 
  WHERE
   group_name=:group_name, 
   group_leaders=:group_leaders, 
   soas_short_cd=:soas_short_cd, 
   phone_number=:phone_number, 
   email=:email 
  LIMIT 1";
$alloc_id_stmt = $dbh->prepare($get_allocation_id);
$alloc_id_stmt->bindParam(":group_name", $params['group_name']);
$alloc_id_stmt->bindParam(":date_submitted", $params['date_submitted']);
$alloc_id_stmt->bindParam(":group_leaders", $params['group_leaders']);
$alloc_id_stmt->bindParam(":soas_short_cd", $params['soas_short_cd']);
$alloc_id_stmt->bindParam(":phone_number", $params['phone_number']);
$alloc_id_stmt->bindParam(":email", $params['email']);
$alloc_id_stmt->execute();
```

The above code is in a PHP file that is called by an ajax request which supplies $params.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL syntax is invalid; `WHERE` clause conditions must separated by logical `AND` (or `OR`, but we assume you mean to sue `AND` in this case), but you have separated them by commas:

```
  SELECT id
  FROM form1_group_info 
  WHERE
   group_name=:group_name
   /* Insert logical AND */
   AND group_leaders=:group_leaders 
   AND soas_short_cd=:soas_short_cd 
   AND phone_number=:phone_number
   AND email=:email 
  LIMIT 1;
```

As mentioned above, you are also binding a parameter which is not used in your query.  Perhaps you mean:

```
  SELECT id
  FROM form1_group_info 
  WHERE
   group_name=:group_name 
   AND group_leaders=:group_leaders 
   AND soas_short_cd=:soas_short_cd 
   AND phone_number=:phone_number
   AND email=:email
   /* forgot this one... */
   AND date_submitted=:date_submitted
  LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Wow I need to take a break. Thanks.

Comment: ... and don't use commas between WHERE conditions

Answer (score 2):

It would help if you included the error. That said, I believe the problem is:

```
$alloc_id_stmt->bindParam(":date_submitted", $params['date_submitted']);
```

You're not using that parameter in your query.